# iText reading multicolumned PDF document

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

**Reading multicolumned PDF document**

When iText read the PDF (Extract a page content into a string variable), then the content would be fixed there by:

```
reader = new PdfReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.resume1));
original_content = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2);
String sub_content = original_content.trim().replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");
sub_content = sub_content.trim().replaceAll("\n ", "\n");
sub_content = sub_content.replaceAll("(.+)(?<!\\.)\n(?!\\W)", "$1 ");
```

if the document is 1 column only but if the document has multicolumn, it would extract the document 1 per line. it would combine left and right column.

I am using [this](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/infolab/publications/Katz-ForeignLanguage.pdf) as a sample PDF this is from START QA document.

**How to read a multicolumned PDF document?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different approaches to this problem, and the choice which to use depends on the PDF itself.

1. *If strings in the page content of the PDF in questions already are in the desired order:* Instead of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` implicitly used by the overload of `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage` you use, explicitly use the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`; in your case:

   ```
   original_content = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
   ```
2. *If the strings in the page content of the PDF in question are **not** in the desired order:* Instead of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` implicitly used by the overload of `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage` you use, explicitly wrap one such strategy in a `FilteredTextRenderListener` restricting it to receive text for the area of a single column only; in your case:

   ```
   Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 306, 792);
   Rectangle right = new Rectangle(306, 0, 612, 792);
   RenderFilter leftFilter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(left);
   RenderFilter rightFilter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(right);
   [...]
   TextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), leftFilter);
   original_content = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2, strategy);
   originalContent += " ";
   strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), rightFilter);
   original_content += PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2, strategy);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, mkl. I have tried both of the code you have posted and the second approach worked with both 1 columned and 2 columned pdf with my requirement. I have a problem with first approach it seems that it removes double `\n` when extracted from the pdf aside from that no problems with multicolumned pdf (Have not tried with 3 or more columned PDF doc). By the way, is it possible that the first approach would only extract the PDF without editing the form of the content?

Comment: Actually the first approach (SimpleTextExtractionStrategy) is the one doing the least manipulations to the page content, it only inserts spaces and line breaks where suggested by coordinate jumps. The second approach does way more along the lines of coordinate analysis of individual text segments.

Comment: Thanks mkl but I only want the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` to extract the contents without manipulating `\n`.

Comment: You can simply copy the strategy source code (iText is OSS after all) and remove the additionof newline chars in your copy.